# How to send an email in iOS6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5

I have been following a tutorial series and I am trying to learn how to send an email.

I typed in the following line of code but it says it was deprecated in iOS 6.

```
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

What would be the replacement  for this code in iOS 6 be and would it work on iOS 5 devices?

Comment: Thanks for downvoting and not explaining why. very helpful!

Comment: Tip - option click most symbol in Xcode will bring up quick help which has a link to the full docs. They will explain what to use instead. Doing just this little bit shows good faith and willingness to help yourself and will increase the effectiveness of answers you get. Hope this helps.

Comment: @CarlVeazey Thanks to the help.

Comment: @CarlVeazey Yeah tried this and it does say which one to use. Thanks for the advice will help me in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That method was deprecated and is replaced by

```
presentViewController:animated:completion:
```

But really, that's right at the top within the documentation of `presentModalViewController:animated:`.